# android sherlock spinner wont wrap text in headline

Tags: android, text, actionbarsherlock, width, spinner

i have s spinner in sherlock action bar

```
<com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.IcsSpinner
    android:id="@+id/action_bar_spinner"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="5"
     />
```

my problem is that the text wont fit in (one line)
and setting different font size doesn't seem to change anything .

how can make sure the text will be fit in nice like scale text or something like that  ?

[image: this :]

[image: become this :]

as you can see in the second picture the text is bacame 2 lines instead on size the text down .

what can i do to makes its on nice line ?